# Why is OnAssemblyStart not being called with the latest MSpec/ReSharper?

Tags: resharper, mspec

We're using MSpec 0.9.3. After we upgraded to ReSharper 9.1, our tests started to fail. `IAssemblyContext::OnAssemblyStart` was no longer being called.

This is a workaround:

```
public class AllTests : IAssemblyContext
{
    static AllTests()
    {
        //Workaround
        TestSetup();
    }

    public void OnAssemblyStart()
    {
        //TestSetup(); //Only in R#8
    }

    public void OnAssemblyComplete()
    {
        //Not called in R#9
        TestSession.Clean(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/agross/AssemblyContextSpecs

Comment: The issue tracker might be a more appropriate place to ask about this. Unless you're not certain about how you're using OnAssemblyStart. But, it looks like you've got it setup right.

https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues